# sort custom date format in google sheet pivot and chart

Tags: date, sorting, google-sheets, custom-formatting

I set the format of the date in my google sheet so it display 'YY' and 'MMM' (eg: Jan-22, Feb-22). but when it pivoted, it's not in date order, but in alphabetical order (as of: Feb-22 before Jan-22).
is there a way I can sort the pivot and then the chart so it will be in date order?

[pivot with unordered date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmHSK.png)

[chart with unordered date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1Pyg.png)

Comment: We can't tell you anything from images. If you'd like, share a link to the spreadsheet (or to a copy of it), as the volunteer contributors here will need to see the underlying data and several sheet settings to assess the problem and offer meaningful solutions.

Comment: look into QUERY as a substitution for the whole pivot table